# Flexbox gallery layout without stretching images of different sizes

Tags: html, css, web, flexbox, frontend

I've been trying to achieve something like this gallery style layout using flexbox: [Example of desired outcome](http://ofanother.com/)

I want images (regardless of size) to sit next to each other in a two column layout until mobile layout where it's only 1 image for each line. When the two images sit next to each other I want them to scale to the size of the largest one of the two without stretching or distorting either picture.

My current attempt can be found here: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/Joshua-Ronan-Phillips/pen/EZrjyq)

You can see that I've tried two methods, each have resulted in different problems.

I'll stick to the stretched image issue as that's currently closest to my desired outcome.

```
    <div class="wrapper">
  <header>
    MY HEADER
  </header>
  <section>
    <a href="" class= "unitie">
      <img src="http://www.landscapes.org/london/wp-content/uploads/sites/8/2015/09/roadmap-to-landscapes-finance.jpg" />
    </a>
    <a href="" class= "meow">
      <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/bd/99/3e/bd993e9921e1131fef606fcd99a03494.png" />
    </a>
</section>
  <footer>
    2016
  </footer>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  display: flex;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

a {
  width: 48%;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

I found this idea online: [Using aspect ratio for flex property](https://kartikprabhu.com/articles/equal-height-images-flexbox)
But I have no idea how to find the aspect ratio of any image and convert it into the flex grow property value like he did.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you need `height:100%` on your `img` tags? Removing this would stop the images from vertically stretching. Unfortunately if you want the items to sit evenly in a two column layout (i.e. in perfect vertical and horizontal rows like in your example) without stretching the images, then all the images would have to be the same aspect ratio. If two photos have different aspect ratios, one of them will have to either be squished oddly or be cropped to match the other.

Comment: "When the two images sit next to each other I want them to scale to the size of the largest one of the two without stretching" - if you want the smaller image to scale to the larger image, how do you expect to do that without stretching the smaller one?

Answer (score 1):

Lot going on here.

First, make sure all your html tags close correctly.
Second, its `class="name`" not `class "name"`

Finally, the only way to make an html, inline image to fit a container is to have remove it from pageflow and then absolute position it so it is either taller or wider than its container based on the image properties.

The easiest way to do this is to move it into a css background image.

  `<a href="" class="unitie grid--image" style="background-image:url('image.jpg')>
    </a>`

`.grid--image {
 background-size: cover;
}`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks @im_benton Follow up question, I thought it would be better to put both background-image:url and background-size: cover; inside the class styles for each unique a tag, but when I do that here: http://codepen.io/Joshua-Ronan-Phillips/pen/EZrjyq it seems the images aren't visible. I always thought inlines styles were bad practice, but is it necessary here?

Comment: Looks like adding a height of say 200px brings the images back but I want to have the height auto adjust to the largest picture, height: auto; isn't displaying the images at all.

Comment: this should work: `<div style="background-image:url('image.jpg'); background-size: contain;">`

Comment: I've added background-size: contain; to each class rule but they still aren't visible. The MDN description for contain talks about: "Image is letterboxed within the container" both the section and the a tags don't have a width or height which may be why they aren't appearing. I can get them to appear if the section container has a height of 100vh but there is still odd behavior in image sizes if the window is made to be different sizes. Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way? What is the standard solution for putting different sized images inside a fluid gallery grid?

Comment: Yes, without content in the box, the box will collapse. the browser won't respect the size of the image if it's in css. So you can set a manual height or padding.

Comment: There are lots of ways to go about creating it, it all depends on what you are doing. Ideally you could just crop all the images to be a box with the same ratio.